# drupal 7: How do I add individual css elements to an existing module css

Tags: theming

drupal 7: How do I add individual css elements to an existing module css so that if later on when this module css is updated when the module is updated my individual css are not deleted?

Comment: I'd suggest you leave the module's files alone, and add the css over-rides at the theme level. I generally keep a theme css file specifically for this purpose

Comment: How do I insure that the css over-rides at the theme level only over-rides a particular modules css and does not over-ride over modules css (does not globally over-rides within this theme)?

Comment: If you provide equivalent specificity to the module's css statements, this shouldn't be an issue. If it is an issue, then the module's css would experience the same conflict

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You are supposed add your individual CSS files in your custom themes (possibly [sub-themes](http://drupal.org/node/225125) of existing ones) or in your custom module.

In both cases, do it using `stylesheets[all][] = your.css` clausule in [module's .info file](http://drupal.org/node/542202) or [theme's .info file](http://drupal.org/node/171205).